# Which system works is the best?

Tags: architecture, distributed

I have an application that runs under 16 Weblogic instances, distributed on 4 servers.

On top of that, I have 2 Apache servers, that are communicating with the application servers.

And on top of that, I have a load balancing system (CSS card, that is going to be replaced by another type of card - ACE card-).

This works fine.

But my company would like to get rid of the 2 Apache Servers, and integrate one IIS instance which will communicate with one Weblogic instance.

So basically, I'll have:

- 16 IIS instances, speaking with 16 Weblogic instances, with a 1-1 relationship.

Personally, I'm very skeptical about this architecture, because:

- what could happen if a Weblogic instance goes down ? I mean, the IIS instance still continues to receive requests from the load balancing system. I know that the new load balancing system can first send a request to see if the application is responding, and if so, it will let the request go further. But, I can imagine that this is taking quite a lot of time, and it's not good for performance.
- Moreover, if the application is responding (meaning Weblogic is UP and running), but this time, IIS is not, the load balancing system will send the request to an IIS instance that is down. So users will have to wait forever!

Do you see other benefits or big drawbacks of this new solution that I may have missed? Is it a good architecture solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works fine.

It's the best solution then.

Your problem statement does not indicate the drivers for the change. Instead, it simply analyzes a solution (for an unclear problem). One cannot determine if a solution would be good or bad without knowing the drivers that form it.

Comment: There is a clear problem. I may be able to stop it before it's too late. So, I modified the title of the problem. I need to know if the new solution is good for Production use, and if not, why : are there any drawbacks that I'm not aware of, or anything else. I wish that you were right when you say "It's the best solution then", but I need to proove that.

Comment: If something works well already, there should be a clear reason for the change. If not, what exists now is the best to continue with. A mere preference ('like' in your description) is not a credible driver for a change. That's what's not clear here. What makes an already working thing to be changed? Why that preference? What is to be accomplished that is not present in the current working system? If you question like that, you may sometimes identify that this change is not something that is really needed. If credible reasons are found, then only the new solution can be gauged against them.

Comment: Thanks Kamal. But the thing is that, in a big company, this is not always the way it works. Some people may bring their own solution, and these people may be very important ones. So, the logical way is not always preferred. And so, some "wrong" solutions may come to PRODUCTION.So, what I need right now, is a good level of expertise that can make me understand better the good points (if there are) to the new solution (IIS). How can it fit well with load balancers ? How can it work with Weblogic in case of an incident on Weblogic etc... All limit cases. With both solutions.

Comment: Generally, for a single request, load on front end servers are low. So a 1-1 mapping suggests that front end server utilization of new solution will be low. It is a cost issue. In a 1-many mapping, web server also performs load balancing/fault tolerance. New solution does not have that but moved to the load balancer. There is an unnecessary cost due to unnecessary communication if an app server fails. But that MAY not be a great issue. Otherwise, both are very much the same. In new solution, full load balancing/fault tolerance depend only on load balancer. Have a reliable device.

Comment: But a best design cannot be identified this way. To optimize the utilization, we need to make informed decessions about load disitribution between app servers and web servers. That tells us what the mapping should be. Check the proposed connectivity mechanism between IIS and WebLogic at the IIS end. How fast the load balancer would be able to detect if WebLogic fails? This is a key point to check. While the good solution will work, I don't say it would be a good pick since the selection means is poor. So don't expect it to be a cost saver. It may or may not.

Comment: Your actual problem is not having an IT governance function in your organization. Particularly change management. If you are from a big company, consider establishing an IT governance function or an enterprise architecture function, or a change management practice, or at least some technology principles. To get a limited view, read TOGAF architecture change management of ADM. Also check example technology architecture principles (for example, Requirements-Based Change).

Comment: Correction: "While the good solution will work" -> "While the new solution will work"

Comment: For more clarity: How can you scale out the existing solution? Say you increase Apache count to 16 and connect each Apache instance to 8 WebLogic instances (so in total you have 16x8 WebLogics). That's a scaled up version of existing solution. Now from each branch, remove 7 WebLogic instances. That's what your new solution is except that Apache has been replaced with IIS. It's not equal to 7 out of 8 WebLogics being down in each branch, but to not connected. The difference is that when only 1 is connected, web server doesn't even try to tag failed Web Logics. Only the ratio is poor here.

Comment: ... the ratio between web servers and WebLogics. But you see, there are other things to look at too. There are concerns about isolating applications for security reasons. They may be plans to deploy such different applications in different servers and so on...

Comment: "That tells us what the mapping should be. Check the proposed connectivity mechanism between IIS and WebLogic at the IIS end. How fast the load balancer would be able to detect if WebLogic fails? This is a key point to check." => I have no way to know this, unfortunately. Because, even the guys that are proposing that solution don't know it.

Comment: "To get a limited view, read TOGAF architecture change management of ADM. Also check example technology architecture principles (for example, Requirements-Based Change)." Thanks for this, I'll give that a serious look. And, by the way, I agree that we lack a lot of things here. But, actually, I've asked Oracle. And they suggest that we keep the existing solution. Thanks Kamal for these explanations.